# Inaport Lookups can't find target entity - CRM4 Connector

Tags: dynamics-crm-4, data-migration

The documentation for inaport states you can just map lookup fields and it will work out what types they are.

I am mapping from CRM 4 to CRM 2011 (using the CRM Connectors), however all my lookups fail with

```
A lookup value was mapped to account.{field name} but no target entity name was supplied and no default is available.
```

I have to fall back to adding a custom field, checking if their is a lookup id in the field, and then making a lookup value as per the documentation of guid::entityname using expressions which is painful.

Is this feature working for anyone else? Do i need to set up a child-parent relationship? I only ever add a map for the entity I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inaport will try to work out what the correct entity reference is and default it. For example, if the lookup is the foreign key in a child table, the entity reference will default to the parent.

There are some circumstances where a lookup may reference multiple entity types, and Inaport cannot infer the correct type. For example, and activity "regarding" lookup may reference 12 different entity types.

It could do a better job when a custom lookup is only referencing a single entity type, and a change request has been put into the system.

As you noted, when Inaport does not correctly infer the entity type you can force it by appending "::entityname" to the GUID you are mapping to the lookup field. This is discussed in more detail in the help.

HTH

Regards

David Evans